# Uninstall extension from experimental window C# - VS 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, uninstallation, vsix

I am creating vsix project that is **Editor Classifier** (a template for managing editor content). I executed the project, the plugin was installed in that experimental window. It always worked properly. but when I install another plugin (e.g. a **menu command** or a **tool window**), the previous plugin overlaps the current one.

I tried to uninstall the plugin directly from **experimental window** from **Manage Extentions** menu. All the previous extensions got uninstalled properly by doing this, but when I try to reinstall them, It could not be installed.

Comment: Hi friend, try to delete the component cache from the path `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxxxx\ComponentModelCache` to check the issue persists.

Comment: Did your issue still persists? Please feel free to let us know whether it works:)

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Yeah! Sure. Whatever happens, I'll communicate.

Comment: Hi, what the error message when you reinstalled them? And could you please share the log with us? It will be helpful for us to troubleshoot your issue. Or try to uninstall all extensions by deleting files.(delete all the files from `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxx\Extensions` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions`).

Answer (score 2):

> All the previous extensions got uninstalled properly by doing this,
>   but when I try to reinstall them, It could not be installed.

This issue is more related to extension caches or for some reason it didn't uninstall cleanly.

So please try these steps to troubleshoot your issue:

1. please check whether the installed extension is still under [the folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-using-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2019#per-user-and-administrative-extensions) and make sure that they are uninstalled cleanly.
2. try to delete the extension cache files under the path `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxxxx\ComponentModelCache` and sometimes the extension is uninstalled on vs, but the cache is not removed, and the cache is detected to be uninstalled during installation.

And by the way, delete the system temp files under the path `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp`.

3. try to [do a repair in the VSInstaller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) to check whether VS is broken.

**In addition**, if your VS2019 is not the latest version, please update it and see whether the issue persists.

Hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [Clean up the experimental environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-an-extension-with-a-menu-command?view=vs-2022#clean-up-the-experimental-environment).
Quote:

> If you are developing multiple extensions, or just exploring outcomes with different versions of your extension code, your experimental environment may stop working the way it should. In this case, you should run the reset script. It's called Reset the Visual Studio Experimental Instance, and it ships as part of the Visual Studio SDK. This script removes all references to your extensions from the experimental environment, so you can start from scratch.