# Powershell file path with space, multiple drives

Tags: powershell, filepath

I'm trying to use the call operator (&) to run an R script, and for some reason I am unable to direct to the right path on the D:\ drive, but it works fine on the C:\ drive (copied the R folder from D:\ to C:\ for testing).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/su8oc.jpg]

The D:\ drive error appears like a space error, even though there are quotes around the string/variable.

Double spacing between "Program" and "Files", the call command reads correctly.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLinf.jpg]

Ideally I would like to call to Rscript.exe on the D:\ drive, but I don't know why it's giving me an error - especially when the C:\ drive works fine and double spacing reads correctly.

Also worth noting "D:\Program Files (x86)" doesn't read correctly either, with similar symptoms.

Update: running

```
    gci -r d:\ -include rscript.exe | % fullname
```

returns:

D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe

D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe

D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\Rscript.exe

The last of which is what my variable $RscriptD is set to.

Comment: Error messages look like `stderr` output from executable file converted to PowerShell `ErrorRecord`.

Comment: My bets are that it's not where you think it is; run  `gci -r d:\ -include rscript.exe | % fullname` and post the results.

Comment: Did you try to set `"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe"` or `"D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe"` to `$RscriptD`? Same result?

Comment: @matt9 ".\i386\Rscript.exe" and ".\x64\Rscript.exe" work! Don't know what's up with the last link, but for my purposes using the other links will do. Do you know why ".\Rscript.exe" doesn't read properly? Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: @AlexL Rscript.exe cannot handle a whitespace well, I think. See the below answer. And if you have time, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845809/c-program-is-not-recognized-error) and try `D:\Progra~1` instead of `D:\Program Files`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error message in your image is:

> Rscript.exe : The term 'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

This message means that the call operator (`&`) called Rscript.exe but Rscript.exe failed to do something by using 'D:\Program'.

I don't know exactly the details of internal process of Rscript.exe, however, I think Rscript.exe tried to run `D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\i386\Rscript.exe` or `D:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe` but could not handle the whitespace of `Program Files`. Because the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Sub_002darchitectures) says:

> Sub-architectures are also used on Windows, but by selecting executables within the appropriate bin directory, **R_HOME/bin/i386** or **R_HOME/bin/x64**. **For backwards compatibility** there are executables R_HOME/bin/R.exe and **R_HOME/bin/Rscript.exe**: these will **run an executable from one of the subdirectories**, which one being taken first from the R_ARCH environment variable, then from the --arch command-line option and finally from the installation default (which is 32-bit for a combined 32/64 bit R installation).

According to this, I think it is better to call directly i386/Rscript.exe or x64/Rscript.exe rather than bin/Rscript.exe which is just for backwards compatibility.